# sql select last n rows, sort them reversed

Tags: mysql, sql

From an ordered (by `datetime`) table, I need to get last 9 rows.

Since I use...

```
SELECT fecha_hora
  , estado_viejo
FROM cambios_de_estado 
WHERE usuario_id = '35512'
ORDER BY fecha_hora DESC
LIMIT 9
```

...the output is inverted.

I need to get the original order.

The query is longer. This is the tricky part for me.

Comment: Probably you need to change the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: But, how? Cannot find the way.

Comment: Consider removing the `DESC` keyword from the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: If you're using MySQL >= 8.0, you can use window functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery:

```
SELECT ce.*
FROM (SELECT fecha_hora, estado_viejo
      FROM cambios_de_estado 
      WHERE usuario_id= '35512'
      ORDER BY fecha_hora DESC
      LIMIT 9
     ) ce
ORDER BY fecha_hora ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your query inside another one, ordering the external one by the column `fecha_hora` ascending:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT fecha_hora
    , estado_viejo
  FROM cambios_de_estado 
  WHERE usuario_id = '35512'
  ORDER BY fecha_hora DESC
  LIMIT 9
) AS t
ORDER BY t.fecha_hora ASC
```

Comment: How is this different from Gordon's answer?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to re-edit the way you are asking your question because it's not clear.

But you may need to use

ASC instead of DESC

ASC means old date to new date (Increasing)
DESC means new date to the old date (Decreasing)

```
SELECT fecha_hora
  , estado_viejo
FROM cambios_de_estado 
WHERE usuario_id = '35512'
ORDER BY fecha_hora ASC
LIMIT 9
```